# getting file path with '/'

Tags: python, os.path

How to get 'path/to/file/'

This is missing the last '/'

```
In [2]: os.path.join('path', 'to', 'file')
Out[2]: 'path/to/file'
```

This does not help:

```
In [3]: os.path.join('path', 'to', 'file', '/')
Out[3]: '/'
```

Comment: I'm curious: why do you want a final slash on the filename?

Comment: I am concatenating 2 os.path.joins

Comment: If you concatenate two path joins then your code shoud look like `os.path.join(os.path.join('path', 'to', 'file'), os.path.join('second', 'path'))` and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it yourself: `os.path.join('path', 'to', 'file') + os.path.sep`

Answer (score 1):

have your tried: os.path.join('path','to','file'+os.sep)